# iTextPDF BaseFont reading font from database

Tags: java, itext

Does someone do loading font file in iTextPDF from database? When loading font, for example:

```
BaseFont.createFont("res/mycustomfont.ttf", BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

it's loaded from local filesystem.

I have read iText in action 2E, (especialy I have repeated chapter 11 now) but none about loading fonts from database, just how to load them from file system.

Going through source code, looks that for true type font (example above) the real data read is done in TrueTypeFont#process(byte ttfAfm[], boolean preload) and it reads from local filesystem only.

Curious if someone have override it for reading font data from DB?

Comment: At first glance it looks like the architecture of the iText font classes (at least for true type fonts; fonts given as afm/pfm files are a different matter) assumes fonts to be present in the file system. You, therefore, should read the fonts required for your PDF from database and store them in some temporary folder. Having created that document, you can delete them again.

Comment: @mkl to me it looks that classes for truetype fonts doesn't assume that font files will be stored on any other place than filesystem. storing them in temp folder as you described should be solution but has some pitfalls.